# Change one number to get arithmetical sequence

Tags: javascript

I have 3 numbers and I need to change exactly one number to get arithmetic sequence. The difference must be as small as possible.

**For example if I have numbers 10 19 30 I have three options:**

1, change `19` to `20` (difference will be 1) and sequence is `10 20 30` (step by 10)

2, change `30` to `28` (difference will be 2) and sequence is `10 19 28` (step by 9)

3, change `10` to `8` (difference will be 2) and sequence is `8 19 30` (step by 11)

I will choose the first option, because I want the minimum difference. So the result will be 1.

**I write a javascript program to solve it but it sometimes give me wrong result and I don't know why:**

```
var nums = [961587, 704764, 380219];

var a = nums[0];
var b = nums[1];
var c = nums[2];

var diff = ((b - a) + (c - b)) / 2;

var result = Infinity;
if(a + diff !== b && a + diff + diff !== c) {
    result = Math.min(result, Math.abs(b - diff - a));
}

if(b - diff !== a && b + diff !== c) {
    result = Math.min(result, Math.abs(a + diff - b));
}

if(c - diff !== b && c - diff - diff !== a) {
    result = Math.min(result, Math.abs(b + diff - c));
}

if(result === Infinity) {
    result = 0;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: "change `10` to `8`" is a difference of 2, not 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the general layout of what you need to do:

Pair up your numbers (ie. AB, AC, BC). For each pair, assume that will be your "normal" step (for `AC`, it will be double the step), and determine where the third number would have to fit.

Then compare that calculated third number with your actual third number, and get the difference.

Whichever difference is smaller is your winner.

With that in mind, here's some example code:

```
var adiff = Math.abs(a-(b-(c-b))); // can also be a-2*b+c
var bdiff = Math.abs(b-(a+(c-a)/2); // or b-a/2-c
var cdiff = Math.abs(c-(b+(b-a))); // or c-2*b+a;
switch(Math.min(adiff,bdiff,cdiff)) {
    case adiff:
        alert("A is closest to where it should be: "+a+" => "+(a-2*b+c));
        break;
     case bdiff:
        alert("B is closest to where it should be: "+b+" => "+(b-a/2+c));
        break;
     case cdiff:
        alert("C is closest to where it should be: "+c+" => "+(c-2*b+a));
        break;
}
```

More astute readers will notice that `adiff === cdiff` ;)